# Merge params to devise registration_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am merging the email param into the registration params:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
 end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
end
```

And the params are showing correctly:

```
Parameters: {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
```

But when I try to pass the email param to another page with `<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>` .... the email is nil.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "amount"=>"150.0"}
```

I'm doing the same thing with the other params and I can access them all. Not sure why the email param is not working.

**Update1**

If I pass only the (email: resource.email) into the following the email address appears.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(email: resource.email)
 end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(email: resource.email)
end
```

But the other params are necessary as well.

Is there a way I can access all params and make this work?

Comment: How about `params[:email]` ?

Comment: Nope, I already tried this... I updated the post with more info, if you'd like please take a look!

Comment: You don't need to pass `email` to  new_transaction_path, you can put it in `params`,`params[:email] = resource.email`, then you can access it in the view by `params[:email]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fnagxing.... I'm sorry did you mean do this: `new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params,params[:email] = resource.email])` ???